# using $_GET to pass variables to multiple pages

Tags: php

I've managed to use the GET method to work by (Login Page)

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $url = "Dailyplanner.php?username=" . $username . "password=" . $password;
```

The page i wanted the variables on

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$url = "DailyPlanner.php?username=" . $username. "password=" . $password;
echo "$username $password";
```

Now this works fine apart from two things.

**Number 1:**

When loading the page the values of `$username` and `$password` are shown correctly but some reason it says that password is undefined variable on line 3.

**Number 2:**

I want to access this variable for multiple pages so i copied it over to the pages i wanted and used the following code

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$url = "(the page i want).php?username=" . $username. "password=" . $password;
echo "$username $password";
```

The errors are just saying that username and password are undefined and it doesn't change the url like i want it to. Just wondering if anyone can help. Sorry if this is painful as i am learning PHP. Thanks.

Comment: seems like you should be using `$_SESSION` not passing such information via URL

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per my comment, you should be using `$_SESSION` not passing such information via URL.

on login,

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    //redirect to your dashboard page or authenticated page
}
```

Then on each page, do this

different_page.php

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   //user is logged in
   echo $_SESSION['username'];
}
```

I wouldn't recommend saving password in a session variable. If your aim is to determine a logged in user, use some kind of token, store it in a session and database for the logged in user, then check on every page that both tokens match.

```
//if user credentials check out, generate token and append to session global
$_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
```

Then on each page, check for the above token instead

Comment: Thank you i'll give it a try, Can you explain the token as i wouldn't know how to do that. (edit) Used your method it works wonders appreciate it but just the token thing i need a little help, thanks for fast reply

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie too and I have some suggestion:

First, I think you need to check `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`, not just `$_POST['login']`.

Second: If you want somethings that avaiable in all views, you can use session: [see this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks i'll have a look appreciate the reply

Answer (score 0):

1) you are missing `?username=" . $username. "`**&**`password=" . $password` for get query thats why the password is undefined

2) this approach of passing such vulnerable data is totally bad because it shown password in address panel and worst in referrer header, also you will have to modify every link to keep passing data across the site

you dont need to store whole credential just authorize and store user id in session, password should never be stored anywhere in raw format